# Найти сайт по коду

Tags: веб-программирование

Работаю над сайтом-визиткой. Требованием заказчика является отсутствие каких либо данных о разработчике сайта, кроме того заказчик не сообщает ни имя сайта, ни доменное имя. По условиям ТЗ необходима лишь настроенная CMS (свёрстанный шаблон, настроенное меню, слайдбоксы и т.п.) без контента.

Вопрос:
Что можно вписать в код для того чтобы потом можно было легко найти "свою работу"?

Comment: meta тег, "стучалку" :)

Comment: Хм.. А что это?

Comment: "Стучалка"? Да в сайт встройте код, который будет отправлять запрос с какими-нибудь параметрами на ваш хостинг.

Comment: Зачем Вам ссылка на эту работу? Вы собираетесь её добавить к себе в портфолио или нет? У меня был случай, я так добавил себе работу в портфолио, а потом заказчик гневно требовал её оттуда убрать (причём он её сам нашёл).

Comment: В портфолио которое будет не в открытом доступе. А вообще полагаю вопрос "Зачем?" здесь неуместен.

Comment: А как вы собираетесь его находить, если доменное имя неизвестно? В любом случае вставьте какой-нибудь ответ на что-то хитрое, типа `test.ru/?20ec27c5b1073a563ad05f608a8038944317e3b`. Или наоборот, чтобы он сам дёргал ваш скрипт.

Comment: В стилях, в JS или прямо в разметке сделай ссылку на свой PHP скрипт, который отдает image/png размером 1×1 (опционально), перед этим сохраняя себе все содержимое $_SERVER. Потом просто удалишь этот файл.

Answer (score 3):

1. «звонок домой-JS» — Если для сайта написали немаленький js, можно в него же включить ф-ю, которая проверяет, не наступила ли отдалённая дата (чтобы не бомбить вас вечно), и рандомно, раз в n визитов, рисующая в документ невидимую картинку-счётчик с вашего сайта. В немного запутанном и обфусцированном виде, чтобы прямо строки с url вашего сайта целиком не было, разумеется. Затем js минифицируете, и фиг кто-то что-то найдёт (скорее всего). Так вы получите достаточно хитов, и поймёте, где живёт ваше творение. А после "той даты" эта звонилка сама собой совсем отключится и не будет никому мешать.
2. «звонок домой-CSS» – где-то в CSS внедрить вызов картинки-счётчика;
3. ваш специфический текст, который проиндексируется, но невидим из-за `overflow:hidden; text-indent:-9000px` (не `display:none`) — через пару недель погуглите — может, найдётся.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img style="display:none" src="ewrgujsew.jpg">
```

Часто такой опознавательный знак используют

Comment: Так а как же потом найти свой сайт?

Comment: 2 раза уже сказали как...